# How to prevent clients from retrieving my server's certificate

Tags: authentication, ssl, asp.net-web-api, web-applications, certificate

I have a secure API for mobile clients. I would like to perform certificate pinning and I achieved it. The problem is if run the command `openssl s_client -connect xxx.xxxxxxxxx.com:443` then I can see my certificate. I believe whoever have the URL, they can also see the certificate and they connect to my APIs.

How I can prevent access to my certificate, so that only my mobile can access but not public?

Comment: At the TCP/IP socket layer, there is no way to identify a client (like a mobile browser). The TLS WG considered a field to support it, but eventually declined it because they were concerned about protocol complexity and user tracking. It comes up from time to time on the TLS WG, especially when a SSL/TLS stack has a bug. The idea is, SSL stack fingerprinting allows the server to work around client bugs. The last time it came up was Apple's [SecureTransport bug in ECDSA](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL_OP_SAFARI_ECDHE_ECDSA_BUG).

Comment: When you want to filter clients at the socket level, you usually use IPsec. All your mobile clients would establish a VPN to the server, and only those mobile clients can access the services. Regarding pinning, see [Certificate and Public Key Pinning](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning) on OWASP.

Comment: The [tag:asp.net-web-api] tag is being discussed on Meta at [Why does web-api tag redirects to asp.net-web-api?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354012/608639) The short of it is, the [tag:web-api] tag likely should not redirect to [tag:asp.net-web-api] tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyone who connects to an SSL / TLS server can view the server's certificate because is public. This is normal behavior.

But that does not mean it can connect to your API. Normally an authentication mechanism is added where the one that connects has to present credentials, for example `user/password`.

With SSL/TLS is also possible to require a client certificate to stablish the secure channel. This is called **two ways authentication**. But it is not usually used from mobile devices because of the difficulty of distributing the electronic certificates

I suggest adding authentication to your api if you have not already done so

Comment: Mutual authentication is a good choice, too. I recommend client certificates in place of the traditional shared key stuff, too. A network based attacker can learn or discover a shared API key through a number of tricks. Its even built into standards like [RFC 7469, Public Key Pinning with Overrides](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7469) (known good pinsets are broken for the attacker). A network based attacker cannot recover the client's private key.

Comment: Hi Pedrofb/Jww, Agree with your approach. Yes my mobile app have user id/pwd authentication and added some token mechanism for added security feature. Only worry is if some one JailBroke their phone, they they may be able to view all my app details (i.e. What token we are passing from our app). Wondering how to handle this situation. Validates client certificates in our server would be interesting. Let me google it and see how to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

Public key cryptography works by having one part (the certificate) freely available publicly. The corresponding private key is needed to decrypt and it should be kept secret.

Therefore there is no problem with openssl having access to the certificate - that's exactly how it should work! A web browser will also be able to grab the certificate for a website it had not been too.

Pinning adds a further layer of security that this but limiting the certificates that a website can use to those certificates that are "pinned" to the site. As discussed without the private key, someone can decrypt the traffic. However there are certain, reasonably sophisticated attacks that involve intercepting traffic and replacing the certificate with another using their own certificate/private key combination so they **can** read the traffic. Pinning prevents this by explicitly stating which certificate(s) should be allowed in this site.

Pinning does not stop the need for the key to be public, nor does it limit connections from your mobile app only - there are other solutions for that but pinning is not it. It merely is used to address one type of attack against the server.

Pinning is an advanced topic and it is easy to accidentally cut off access to your site by pinning a certificate and then not updating the pins when renewing, or otherwise changing, the certificate. Due to that risk, you should ensure you have a **much** greater understanding of how all this works before implementing pinning. At the moment you seem to have a misunderstanding of the basics so would advise against advanced topics like pinning.